# Getting error gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 255

Tags: cocoa

When I am trying to run a cocoa application on my snow leopard i getting the following error

Command /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 255

Comment: Is that a question?  Some more details would be helpful if you're looking for help finding a solution.

Comment: I have developed a cocoa application. But when I am building the application on Snow Leopard it is generating the above error. How can i resolve it?

Comment: Can you add the full output of GCC ? Maybe some elements are in the prievious line.

Answer (score 0):

Is not clear, but you say

> trying to run a cocoa application

and it return a error on GCC. Ok, this program are using GCC and it return 255. What this mean?

In the [GCC manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html), this number only say: the GCC finish with a error, nothing more. With not more information, is just this.